# Why i am getting type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte

Tags: java, byte

```
class Test
{  
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   { 
     byte t1 = 111;
     byte t2 =11;
     byte t3 = t1+t2;

     System.out.println(t1+t2);   

   }  
}
```

In eclipse it is showing error `cannot convert from int to byte`.Here sum  is 122 which range in the byte range.So why i am getting this error here.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Addition results in `int`. you have to explicitly downcast it

Comment: 122 is in the range of byte?

Comment: 122 is in the range of byte. However, the result you see (122) is at `int`. So it needs downcasting

Comment: A byte can hold 256 values. It goes from 0 to 255 for unsigned bytes and from -128 to 127 for signed bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do mathematical operations on byte, Java do Widening( automatic type promotion) to byte(implicitly up casted) to integer this case. so when you perform

```
 byte t3 = t1+t2; //  t1+t2; will be evaluated as integer.
```

As t1+t2 result is wider than byte so you need to downcast it to byte.

To remove compilation error.

```
 byte t3 = (byte) (t1+t2); // typecast to byte
```

For more information please read  [JLS 5.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

Answer (score 0):

```
byte t3 = t1 + t2;
```

For the statement above, the compiler puts the actual values and tries to compute it:

byte t3 = 111 + 11;

However, these numbers are **integer literals**, that's why the compiler complains. You have to do explicit casting:

```
byte t3 = (byte) (t1 + t2);
```

Comment: Actually, this explanation is incorrect. `t1` and `t2` are NOT integer literals.  They are `byte` variables.  The *real* explanation is that integral operands of an arithmetical operator are promoted to (at least) `int`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633949/where-does-the-jls-specify-that-the-result-of-an-addition-is-int-if-its-operands/16634023#16634023