# Where does the JLS specify that the result of an addition is int if its operands are of smaller type?

Tags: java, jls

With reference to [Why i am getting type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633534/why-i-am-getting-ype-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-int-to-byte), I tried a quick search in the JLS to find where is it mentioned that the result of an addition between `byte` operands is automatically widened to `int`.

The best I found was this [tutorial](http://marakana.com/bookshelf/java_fundamentals_tutorial/operators.html), but I didnt' find anything in the JLS.

The [Conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) chapter does not mention anything about the addition operator, at least I couldn't find something. The [Additive Operators paragraph](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18) does not mention automatic widening of byte. It mentions that  `the type of each of the operands of the binary - operator must be a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive numeric type`, but nothing about widening. And byte is a [numeric](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) data type.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there, it is in [15.18.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2):

> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).

Answer (score 3):

In Java 7, the relevant sections are JLS [5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) and the respective section for the operator; e.g. JLS [15.18.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2) for the binary additive operators on numbers.

The operator sections say that binary promotion is performed first.  Then section 5.6.2 explains that binary promotion for `byte`, `short` and `char` means conversion to `int` if the other operand is integral.